# Ревью кода. Найти один отличающейся элемент из трех

Tags: алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Задача: Есть три элемента, один из которых может отличаться от остальных. Нужно его найти.

Допустим есть 3 строковые переменные A,B,C. При этом две переменные A и B будут содержать значение "+", а переменная C значение "-". Нужно отследить, когда в С появиться значение, которое не равно двум остальным.

найти данные последовательности, и отследить какой именно элемент отличается:

```
A:+, B:-, C:+ - отличается (B)
A:+, B:+, C:- - отличается (С)
A:+, B:+, C:+ - все равны
```

Все изначально содержат значение по умолчанию "?". Изменения возможны только на "+" или "-".

Требуется мнение экспертов. Оптимально ли данное решение? Как можно упростить данный код? Возможно, рекурсия тут была бы весьма кстати?

```
boolean bar= false;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (A.equals("+") && B.equals("+")) {
        if (!(A.equals("+") && C.equals("+"))) {
            if (!C.equals("?")) continue;
            bar= true;
            break; // элемент найден
        }
    } else {
        if (A.equals("+") && C.equals("+")) {
            if (!B.equals("?")) continue;
            bar= true;
            break;
        } else {
            if (B.equals("+") && C.equals("+")) {
                if (!A.equals("?")) continue;
                bar= true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Равны между собой или конкретному значению (как у вас)? Тип значений? Один - может или точно отличается?

Comment: сейчас напишу более детально

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что такое `symbol` и к чему он здесь? Что делать, если все три элемента различны? Это ошибка? Или можно найти любой?

Comment: Все стало **еще непонятнее**. Изначально что в переменных? Все одинаковы? Что вы хотите отследить? Все были равны, один стал неравен? Появление минуса в конкретной переменной? Переменную, в которой появился минус?

Comment: Посмотрите дополненный ответ - это устраивает?

Comment: Возможны ли наборы "?+?", "?-?", "+-?"  и т.п.? Или "???" всегда превращаются в +++ или +-+? Что делать, скажем, в случае "?+-"? (Пока что для вашего ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...)

Comment: вопрос задан слишком абстрактно. в следующий раз буду изначально объяснять все как можно более детально

Comment: Не обижайтесь, это же не излишняя придирчивость - просто ответы оказываются совершенно иными при изменении даже на первый взгляд неважного условия.

Comment: @harry все хорошо) я все понимаю! мне правильно посыпались кучи уточнений, сам не люблю когда слишком поверхностно описывают вопросы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В варианте "*Есть три элемента, один из которых отличается от остальных*" - то

```
int a,b,c;
return (a==b) ? c: (a==c) ? b : a;
```

А вот если нужно обрабатывать и "все равны". "все различны" , "равны ли конкретному значению" - это дело другое...

**Update**

Решение, когда все три могут быть равны и равны именно `'+'`, в общем-то, то же самое. Смотрите только, что возвращается. Если `+` - значит, все равны, если `-` - не равны.